# AskUbuntu bug: I renamed my Launchpad account from andy80 to andreagrandi and I cannot access my old data nor use my email account here

Tags: support, user-accounts

I created an AskUbuntu account here, months ago, using my Launchpad account that was named "andy80". In the mean time I renamed my LP account from "andy80" to "andreagrandi".

When I tried to access AskUbuntu again using my Launchpad account I was recognized as a NEW user. So I lost all my contribution made with "andy80" account.

It's not all: even using this new account, I cannot set my email to ************ (censured) because the user "andy80" is already using it.

Who can merge the two accounts and fix this problem please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your accounts have been merged.

Comment: I simply "love" you :D